# Complex plane proof

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that any set consisting of finitely many points are bounded. (complex plane)

I am not sure how to prove this?

Comment: The set is contained in any disk centered at the origin of radius bigger than the maximum of the absolute values of the points. Think geometrically.

Comment: @anon But why would it be bounded? Shouldn't it be an open set? Can you explain to me why it is bounded instead of being an open set please?

Comment: @Q.matin, what is your definition of "bounded set in the complex plane"? Anon's comment can hardly be clearer.

Comment: @Q.matin Bounded and open set are 2 totally unrelated concepts.  A set could be one or the other or both or neither...

Comment: @DonAntonio Is a point $z_0$ is said to be a boundary point of a set $S$ if every neighborhood of $z_0$ contains at least one point of $S$ and at least one point not in $S$.

Comment: @Q.matin "boundary point" has nothing to do with "bounded".

Comment: @Ted ohh wow, that changes everything then.

Comment: A subset of the plane (or a metric space in general) is said to be bounded, or of finite diameter, if it is contained in some disk of specified (so, finite) radius.

Comment: @Ted I understand now. Mental error on my part. I thought they were referring bounded as boundary point. They should change the name :). Thanks for clearing that up!!!!

Comment: @anon Thanks a lot for clearing that up!! Really dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n\}$ is the finite collection of complex numbers, then $max(|z_1|,|z_2|,\cdots,|z_n|)$ lies in the set $\{|z_1|,|z_2|,\cdots,|z_n|\}$. Therefore, for any $k>max(|z_1|,|z_2|,\cdots,|z_n|)$, $|z_i|\lt k$ $\forall i\in \{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$. Thus the set is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$, $r=\max\limits_{1\le i\le n}|a_i|$. Then $A\subset B(0,2r)$. ($B(z,R)$ is open ball whose center is at $z$ and radius $R$.)